# Is that possible to retrieve data from different table using same function in spring JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc

This is my function to get all rows from table player.

```
public List<Player> getAllPlayer() {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM PLAYER";
    List<Player> lstPlayers  = getJdbcTemplate().query(
        sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(Player.class)
    );
    return lstPlayers;      
}
```

I want to get data from another table 'student' using this same function.
Is it possible to get data from both table using same function by changing the 
above code something like below ?

```
public List<Object> getData(String TableName) {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TableName;
    List<Object> lstPlayers  = getJdbcTemplate().query(
        sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(Object.class)
    );
    return lstPlayers;
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Have you tried executing this yourself? It is always recommended to try out the code first and then ask the doubts in case you get any errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the following

```
List<Player> players = getData(Player.class);
List<Student> students = getData(Student.class);

public List<T> getData(Class<T> clazz) {

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + clazz.getSimpleName();
    List<T> lstPlayers  = getJdbcTemplate().query(
            sql,
            new BeanPropertyRowMapper(clazz));

    return lstPlayers;
}
```

However in real life there's not much advantage. It's not that common to want to load all the contents of a database table at once due to performance and other reasons, so this method won't be as helpful as you think.